# Members within a specific age group within one calendar month

Tags: sql

I need to find anyone who was >=6 or <18 per month in 2022.
so for example...even if someone was five on 1/15/2022 and then turned 6 on 1/16/2022 will be counted. or if someone was 17 on 1/20/22 and then turned 18 on 1/21/2022 will still be counted.

im relatively new to sql so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may need to add a Tag for the DBMS you are using, e.g. postgresql or mariadb

Answer (score -1):

The dates are german format, but you should adapt the logic:

```
DECLARE @table Table 
(kd_id int , birthdate DATE)

INSERT INTO @table
(
    kd_id,
    birthdate
)

SELECT 1, '01.10.2016'
UNION
SELECT 2, '09.10.2016'
UNION
SELECT 3, '10.10.2016'
UNION
SELECT 4, '11.10.2016'
UNION
SELECT 5, '17.10.2016'
UNION
SELECT 6, '01.10.2004'
UNION
SELECT 7, '09.10.2004'
UNION
SELECT 8, '10.10.2004'
UNION
SELECT 9, '11.10.2004'
UNION
SELECT 10, '17.10.2004'
UNION
SELECT 11, '01.01.2016'
UNION
SELECT 12, '01.01.2004'
UNION
SELECT 13, '01.01.2017'
UNION
SELECT 14, '31.12.2003'
UNION
SELECT 15, '31.12.2003'
UNION
SELECT 16, '31.10.2004'
UNION
SELECT 17, '30.09.2004'
UNION
SELECT 18, '01.11.2016'

--Query

DECLARE @month NVARCHAR(2) = '10' --October
        ,@year NVARCHAR(4) = '2022'
        ,@month_begin NVARCHAR(10) 
        ,@month_end NVARCHAR(10)

SET @month_begin = '01.' + @month + '.2022'
SET @month_end = EOMONTH(@month_begin) --EOMONTH() = Last date of a month

SELECT kd_id
       ,birthdate
FROM @table
WHERE DATEDIFF(hour,birthdate,@month_begin)/8766 BETWEEN 6 AND 17
OR DATEDIFF(hour,birthdate,@month_end)/8766 BETWEEN 6 AND 17
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please mark my solution as answer. Im new and need some reputation points. ^^ To do so: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. You may change which answer is accepted, or simply un-accept the answer, at any time.